# google apps script how to set trigger on a function in one script from another script

Tags: triggers, google-apps-script

I have a GA script, say, `s1`.

`s1` has 3 functions, `f1`, `f2` and `f3`.

I want to set trigger for `f1` (which is in `s1`) from another script `s2`.

Is it possible to do it?
If yes, how to do it? How to refer to `f1` from `s2`?

The apps documentation on "[managing triggers programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/managing_triggers_programmatically)" says that you need to give function name to set a trigger as given below.

```
  // One-time execution only
  // Use JavaScript Date of 5/17/2012
  var date = new Date(2012, 5, 17);
  var oneTimeOnly = ScriptApp.newTrigger("runCommand")
      .timeBased()
      .at(date)
      .create();
```

It seems, the function "runCommand" must be in the same file.

I also read the documentation about libraries. I have included the script `s1` in `s2`. I can also call methods in `s1` like `s1.f1`, `s1.f2` from `s2`. But I cannot set the trigger.

When I executed:

```
var date = new Date(2014, 2, 17);  
var oneTimeOnly = ScriptApp.newTrigger("s1.f1")
      .timeBased()
      .at(date)
      .create();
```

I got the error: `The selected function cannot be found.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers can only be created for local functions in the project. In order to accomplish what you want you need to create a wrapper function for the library function in the project